# How to aggregate arrays of days weekly in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs, aggregate

For example, take the time range from 05/10/2019 to 05/25/2019.

Dates on this interval need to be aggregated like this (`2019` is omitted for brevity):

```
const result = [
  [                                    '05-10', '05-11', '05-12'], // week 1
  ['05-13', '05-14', '05-15', '05-16', '05-17', '05-18', '05-19'], // week 2
  ['05-20', '05-21', '05-22', '05-23', '05-24', '05-25'         ], // week 3
];
```

What is the best way to solve this problem with JS?
Is it possible to implement this by setting the beginning of the week on any day?
Will packages [`moment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) and [`moment-range`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range) help in this?

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the dates, and if the day is `1` (Monday), create a `new Array` in your results:

```js
const startDate = new Date('05-10-2019'),
    endDate = new Date('05-25-2019'),        
    result = [];

function _twoDigits(x) {
  return String(x).padStart(2, '0');
}

let tmp = startDate;
do {
  if (tmp.getDay() === 1 || result.length === 0) {
    // Create a week Array
    result.push([]);
  }
  const str = `${_twoDigits(tmp.getMonth() + 1)}-${_twoDigits(tmp.getDate())}`;
  // Add this date to the last week Array
  result[result.length - 1].push(str);
  // Add 24 hours
  tmp = new Date(tmp.getTime() + 86400000);
} while (tmp.getTime() <= endDate.getTime());

console.log(result);
```

> **Note:** MomentJS may help, but it's a big library. If you only need to do 2 or 3 basic things with dates, I would recommend not using it. If you need to do a lot of work with dates, then yes, it's a powerful library that will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible implementation if you are interested in `moment.js` code.

But as [blex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666564/how-to-aggregate-arrays-of-days-weekly-in-js/58666674#58666674) said it's a large lib.

```js
const start = moment('2019-05-10');
const end = moment('2019-05-25');
const array = [[]];
const from_date = moment(start).startOf('isoWeek');
const to_date = moment(end).endOf('isoWeek');

let j = 0;
let added = 0;
for (let currentDate = moment(from_date); currentDate <= to_date; currentDate.add(1, 'day')) {
  if (added === 7) {
    array.push([]);
    j++;
    added = 0;
  }
  if (currentDate.isBetween(start, end, null, '[]')) {
    array[j].push(currentDate.format('MM-DD'));
  }
  else {
    array[j].push('');
  }
  added++;
}
document.getElementById('output').innerText = JSON.stringify(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<p id="output"></p>
```